# How to connect unity3D with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, unity-game-engine

Can someone give me a tutorial or some demo code? I was confused now.And could not find a suitable driver or library to use.

Answer (score 0):

Simply [googling](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/618708/unity-and-mongodb-saas.html) this would have solved your problem.

You have to build your own driver with the monoDB source code.

1.Change your API Compatibility Level from `.NET 2.0 subset` to `.NET 2.0`.

2.Build the monoDB source driver or you can download already built one (1.10 driver) that works with Unity from the link above. Examples can also be found there.

If you plan to build this yourself, don't build with the 2.x version. Build 1.x version.